# My drop-down not showing up in my templates - django

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

i'm trying to make a nested drop-down with dajngo-mptt for a category section in mt project the code is working and   i can see my codes in inspect but its not showing in my template
can anybody help???
my template:

```
<div class="dropdown">
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            {% recursetree categories %}
                <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
                        aria-expanded="false">
                    {{ node.name }}
                </button>
                
                <li {% if not node.is_leaf_node %}class="dropdown-submenu"{% endif %}>
                    <a class="dropdown-item {% if not node.is_leaf_node %}dropdown-toggle{% endif %}"
                       href="{% if node.is_leaf_node %}{{ node.get_absolute_url }}{% endif %}"
                       {% if not node.is_leaf_node %}role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"{% endif %}>
                        {{ node.name }}
                        {% if not node.is_leaf_node %}<span class="dropdown-caret"></span>{% endif %}
                    </a>

                    {% if not node.is_leaf_node %}
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            {{ children }}
                        </ul>
                    {% endif %}
                </li>
            {% endrecursetree %}
        </ul>
```

veiws.py

```
class HomePage(View):
    def get(self, request, ):
        postss = Post.objects.all()
        categories = Category.objects.all()
        form = CategoryForm()
        return render(request, 'home/index.html', {'postss': postss, 'categories': categories, 'form': form})
```

and i have this js in my base.html

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var dropdownSubmenus = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-submenu'));
    dropdownSubmenus.forEach(function(submenu) {
        submenu.addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {
            this.querySelector('.dropdown-menu').classList.add('show');
        });
        submenu.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
            this.querySelector('.dropdown-menu').classList.remove('show');
        });
    });
});
```

i'm added  to my code and added button to show it but it's not showed up
what can i do?